# Difference between UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and UIViewContentModeScaleToFill?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, contentmode, uiviewcontentmode

what is the difference between **UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit** and **UIViewContentModeScaleToFill**...?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

If you are talking about *UIViewContentMode*, the following is from the [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontentmode).

***UIViewContentModeScaleToFill***

> Scales the content to fit the size of itself by changing the aspect ratio of the content if necessary.

***UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit***

> Scales the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent.

***UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill***

> Scales the content to fill the size of the view. Some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.

Comment: What is an example of where transparency or clipping would occur? I am picturing a rectangle and it seems as if that clause would never be invoked.

Comment: Praxiteles, I am not quite understand your question. But from the context of my answer above, clipping will possibly occur in UIViewContentModeScaleToFill & UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, if the image ratio does not match the imageView's ratio. Please correct me if I have mistaken your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 582):

You can see the differences between the content modes here:

[image]

Redraw mode works as Scale to Fill mode. 
But there is a difference in how they are drawn when view geometry changes.
Scale to Fill mode uses already rendered content while Redraw mode renders the content again.

Answer (score 132):

**[uiimageview-scaling-explained-visually](http://jacksonkr.com/content/uiimageview-scaling-explained-visually)**

[image]