# How to manage UIImageView content mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView with some fixed rect size. But my images are not fixed in size. I want to display images according to UIImageView's rect size. Whether image is big or large in resolution it must be in fixed display according to UIImageView's size. I am confused in using below assets.

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
UIViewContentModeRedraw
```

What to set in autoresize mask ? 
How do they behave ?

Comment: Why don't you check by using the above mentioned values ? You can find the difference easily

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill use tho property of UIImageView content mode. It will fit your image to UIIMageView rect size.

Answer (score 90):

Please try this code, Hope it will work for you.

set `UIImageView` `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` as below :

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

set autoresizingMask of UIImageView as below :

```
imageView.autoresizingMask =   
    ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth );
```

Comment: Update: UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill, and UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin

Comment: There's a way to do this using constraints instead of masks? Or where can I set the masks on the storyboard having constraints enabled?

Comment: i also put clipsToBound = YES;

Comment: Update for Swift 5?

Answer (score 3):

You just need these two lines:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.layer.clipsToBounds = YES; // Must do this or else image will overflow
```

Comment: Thank you! `ClipsToBounds` was my issue. I had it set to `NO` so I could display a shadow around the UIImageView, without thinking about the fact that it'll also let the image bleed over. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution for swift:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backgroundImage"))
imageView.frame = tableView.frame
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
tableView.backgroundView = imageView
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your `UIImageView` size according to ratio ,then you must set it's mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

```
 yourimage.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding.

Comment: No, its not working. Image isn't covering whole area of UIImageView.

Comment: yes, it will not cover the whole area of UIImageview because it will set your image according to ratio, so it will left some area blank according to ratio.so you will get image without blur and get clear image.so  do you want to cover the whole area of UIImageview?

Answer (score 1):

In swift you set content mode as well

```
var newImgThumb : UIImageView
newImgThumb = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 70))
newImgThumb.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that swift 3 has changed as following

.`ScaleAspectFit`  to   `scaleAspectFit`

.`ScaleAspectFill` to  .`scaleAspectFill`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helpful for you

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);

image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```