# How do I resize a user selected image on iOS depending on their screen size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

My app allows a user to select any photo they'd like from their photo library. If the image is bigger than the dimensions of UIImage , the photo will cover the screen (uiimage space is only half the screen). How do I resize the image to take the whole space of the uiImage view that I gave it depending on the size of the devices screen?

Sorry if it's too simple of a question to be asked, but I am new to stack overflow and iOS programming.

Comment: Have a look at the `contentMode` property on your `UIImageView`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage UIImageView content mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134035/how-to-manage-uiimageview-content-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the content mode:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

This will display the image within the UIImageViews's dimension.