# Objective-C: Self-Sizing Table View Cells with dynamic image's height after download

Tags: objective-c, image, uitableview, row-height

I wanna resize imageview'height after download image,but some wrong happened as first cell image when first load tableview;

[image: un normal cell]

then if I scroll table to make the cell be in visible again,it go to be normal as second image;

[image: normal cell]

I don't known the size of image,can't get from server，how to fix it?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ShopingTableCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"shopingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    StoreDynamicsModel *model = storeArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.contentLabel.text = model.name;
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:model.goods_img_url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultShort"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cell.imgViewHeightConstraint.constant = image.size.height * ScreenWidth / image.size.width;
        });
    }];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.f;
    return self.tableView.rowHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set content mode of `UIImageView` to Aspect Fit.

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

For ref:

[How to manage UIImageView content mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134035/how-to-manage-uiimageview-content-mode)

Comment: `[tableview beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];` will force the table view to refresh the heights in an animated fashion. Below codes work  

`if (cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeNone || cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeDisk) {  
[tableView beginUpdates];
 imgViewHeightConstraint.constant = image.size.height * ScreenWidth / image.size.width;
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [tableView endUpdates];
 }`