# how do you make the image size follow the size of the existing image review

Tags: swift, uiimageview, resize

I have an UIimageview but when the picture is taken, the image does not follow the size of UIimageview like this
[image]

I want it like this
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the [`UIImageView`'s `contentMode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134035/how-to-manage-uiimageview-content-mode)?

Comment: I tried it, but the picture became irregular, I want the image to be cut according to the uiimageview, so that it looks good

Comment: Set `clipToBounds` to true. You could also use `aspectToFit` or `aspectToFill` depending on your needs

Comment: right, I tried and succeeded, thanks @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

You should set the clipToBounds property of the UIImageView to true. This will solve your problem. Learn more at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
UIImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```