# What is equivalent to center crop scale type of Android ImageView for iOS UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I would like to ask how to scale an image to fill a `UIImageView` but still keep its aspect ratio, just like the `centerCrop` scale type of Android `ImageView` does.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134035/how-to-manage-uiimageview-content-mode

Comment: Set [`imageView.contentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode) to [`.scaleAspectFill`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode/scaleaspectfill) (or [`.scaleAspectFit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode/scaleaspectfit)).

Comment: @Rob `scaleAspectFit` is equivalent of android `centerInside`

Comment: @iffatfatima - Yep, I just wanted to share both of the aspect preserving scaling `contentMode`s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `.scaleAspectFill`. In swift 4.2:

```
myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
myImageView.clipsToBounds = true // If you want to crop
```

Comment: .scaleAspectFill will stretch the image to fit into UIImageView. If you want to keep the aspect ratio, you should use .scaleAspectFit. The best way is you try both solution in the code to see the final result. If this helps you, please upvote my post. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you're right @Rob. I'll update my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set image view `contentMode` to `UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill`. It is equivalent of Android `scaleType` `centerCrop`

Answer (score 0):

Following are the main content modes of UIImageView:

- UIViewContentModeScaleToFill
- UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
- UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

the one to fill the whole imageview is 'ScaleAspectFill' plus you can also use 'clipsToBound' property as true so that it will crop the extra image which is out of imageview.

Comment: Those are the Objective-C constants, but OP was asking about Swift.

Comment: he can write like imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill & if he want to set the image as its pixels quality .scaleAspectFit will be perfect.