# Maintain image quality in iOS Application

Tags: ios, image, contentmode, uiviewcontentmode

I am trying to create a photo application but I am having a tough time formatting my photos so that they show clearly.

I have an imageview size 320 * 500, and an image size 3648*2736 px (Which of course I can scale down).

```
 imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

With   `imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;` I changed the image size to 700* 525px (IMGA) and one 500 * 325(IMGB). 
In this mode

- IMGA fills the entire image view but is somehow a little distorted/not crisp
- IMGB does not fill the entire image view Top and Bottom but the width is perfect and the image is crisp.

UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
With `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`
the image is made for fit into the uiimageview but again distorted even if the image is scaled down vs being scaled up.

I see many apps with crisp large images . and I am hoping that someone helps me with measuring/ contentmode to get my images better.
Or correct my resizing

P.S I have been looking at this link to try help but I'm still missing my goal.
[Difference between UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and UIViewContentModeScaleToFill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof)

Comment: "IMGB does not fill the entire image view Top and Bottom but the width is perfect and the image is crisp." - this seems like the expected behaviour for UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. the reason it does not 'fill the entire image view top and bottom' is because the image size (500 * 325) does not have the same aspect ratio as the imageview (500 *320).

Comment: Also check how you are scaling your image: 3648*2736 is the same aspect ratio as 700 * 525,  but it is not the same as 500 * 325 ( should be 500 * 375)

Comment: @codeinthesky hi, I decided to use AspectFill. however, are you saying an image with measurements 3648*2736px can somehow fit in a uiimageview if I edit the aspect ratio?
Not entirely sure that I noticed aspect ratio as a property of uiimageview