# How to fill table cell with an image in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am replicating the effect in the image below. I created a custom `UITableViewCell` class with an `UIImageView` property. I set the prototype cell to my custom class. However, I cannot get the table cell's height to resize to the height of the image. There is always space above and below the image.

[image]

Comment: Have you setup the auto-layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the heigh of your `UITableViewCell` dynamic regarding the height of your image. The `UITableViewDelegate` has a function entitled [tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:) that according to Apple:

> Asks the delegate for the estimated height of a row in a specified location.

Then you can in your method ask for the height of the `UIImageView` and set the height for the row properly, see the following example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.getEstimatedHeightForImageAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}

func getEstimatedHeightForImageAtIndex(row: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // here you need to get the height of image for the selected row.
}
```

There is a nice tutorial you can read to know more about the topic :

- [UITableView Tutorial: Dynamic Table View Cell Height](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift)

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to create a custom UITableViewCell, added an UIImageView to the cell and resized it in the storyboard to fill the whole cell.

If you do that though, make sure you add the constraints to have it horizontally and vertically centred, and add the spacing constraints, but change the spacing not to margin (uncheck the box).

See the image below:

[image]

And another thing to remember is the content mode of the imageview. I learned a lot from @EmptyStack and @erkanyildiz answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof).

I hope you found any of this useful, and I am sorry if none of it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UITableViewCell, set cell  style to custom  in storyboard. Add an UIImageView to the cell and resize image to fill the whole cell. Add image outlet to your custom UITableViewCell and use that outlet when seting an image in your TableViewController.

In your **viewDidLoad()** function add 
`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Then you need your *image aspect ratio* (width / height) so you can use it when you set your row height.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath 
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return view.frame.width / CGFloat(aspectRatio)
}
```