# Cropping or centering image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an image in an UIImageView. There are grey portions above and below the image because the image size doesn't have the same size as UIImageView. How can I crop or zoom the image in such a way that it just fits to cover the grey area above and below, or left and right?

[image]

Comment: Blindly scaling image to match imageview will destort the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should set imageview's contentmode to `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill` and you should set propert `clipsToBounds` of imageview to `true`.

by this you will not get that gray space and image will fit in entire imageview.!!

Comment: It should be `.ScaleAspectFill`, as he wants to fill the whole area instead of having grey borders.

Comment: ChaosCoder is right, .ScaleAspectFill worked for me and it covered the grey area. However, I'll upvote and choose your answer as an accepted one because you mentioned the property clipsToBounds which really helped me solve this issue. Only applying AspectFill was not enough since the image was getting out of bounds of UIImageView and setting clipToBounds to true solved this issue. So thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Set the `contentMode` of the UIImageView to `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill`. You can do this programmatically or via Interface Builder.

`yourImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill`

See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) for more details.

Comment: I think you should use .ScaleAspectFit

Comment: No, `.ScaleAspectFill` is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof