# UIView Table Row is stretching , when I change the Iphone model

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm creating an iOS mobile application using Xamarin. I'm new in mobile development, especially on iOS. I have a table view rows, that have background images. So when I'm changing the iphone version from 5s to 6S, they are stretching. I need them to be auto resizable.

[image]

First one is my table view , the second one is the detail view of current row.

Can someone help me with this and at least tell a good topic to read. 
Thanks before hands.

[image]

Here's what I have now , and I just can't remove that left offset that each row has.

Comment: My guess is you simply want to choose **Aspect Fit** or **Aspect Fill**, rather than your current setting.  Just a general comment, I don't know anyone who's ever benefitted from Xamarin; just learn ordinary native development (it's literally much easier).

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to set the constraints on your UIImaveView to set the size and the position of your view.

Then, you have to set your UIImageView's Content Mode to **Scale To Fill** in order to have the image resized automaticaly.

You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof) to understand all Content Mode available.

Comment: It's likely Aspect Fit or Aspect Fill they want - not scale to fill.