# Aspect fit on UIImageView leaves significant whitespace in a UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

So I'm loading an image into a UIImageView, but the image view always leaves significant whitespace on either side. It looks like this:

[image]

Notice the white on either side of the image. Here's the code to set the image:

```
cell.albumArt.sd_setImage(with: result.getImageURL())
```

The imageView is in the aspectFit setting. The constraints are:

- Image leading to super leading
- Image top to super top
- Image bottom to super bottom
- Text leading to image trailing
- Text top to image top

What's going on here? How can I remove the whitespace properly?

Comment: I would imagine from the constraints you have specified there that you're missing a width constraint for the image.

Comment: Aspect Fit *intentionally* leaves whitespace if the image aspect ratio doesn't match the imageview aspect ratio. You can try **Aspect Fill** - but you may not be happy with that result either.

Comment: Try to set a background color to the imageView to differentiate the issue between contentMode and constraints.

Comment: @DonMag isn't there a way to get it to align left so that there isn't any of that whitespace?

Comment: @KerrM Even setting a greater than or equal to width constraint doesn't do anything.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to fit an image with one aspect ratio into a frame that is another aspect ratio. Aspect Fill will fill the frame, but clip off top/bottom or left/right parts of the image. Aspect Fit will fit the entire image into the frame, leaving space on top/bottom or left/right. It's kinda like saying "How come the word *Hello* leaves space on the sides but the word *Acknowledgement* fills the space?"...

Comment: @DonMag I see. It just seems rather odd that the view couldn't shrink it's width to fit the image properly, especially since Android's ImageView supports this functionality.

Comment: If you want the actual ImageView to fit the image size, you have to do that with code... when the image has downloaded, get the dimensions and resize your view as desired. Of course, if you do that, you'll have a whole lotta empty space between the right-edge of your image and the start of the text... unless you *also* adjust the start of the text (which ma or may not be a "good look").

Comment: @DonMag Okay, well thanks for explaining the situation to me. Very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either try `scaleAspectFill` with `clipToBounds == true` or you can set a maximum width and use `scaleAspectFit` which will try to fit the image inside the given constrained frame while keeping the aspect ratio (But leaving white-space on the sides of the frame, accordingly).

`scaleToFill` will wreck your image's aspect ratio.

[This other question in SO has a pretty sweet answer that explains the differences between each mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof)