# Size of cell is not equal to collectionview size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I wrote a code that I got collectionview with 4 cells and I can swipe to see each one of them.

My collectionview backgroundcolor is red and in my cell I put an image (before that I put blue color instead of an image) and I got a problem that I see little red line form the collection view in my cell.

I must say that I had problem that I had bigger line before that and I fix that by hidden navigation view of my viewcontroller.

```
class CheckViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .red
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        return cv
    }()


    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

        view.addSubview(collectionView)


       // collectionView.frame = view.frame

        //use autolayout instead

        collectionView.anchorToTop(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)

        collectionView.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }


//    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
//        return 4
//    }
//

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)


      //  cell.backgroundColor  = .white
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }




}

extension UIView {
    func anchorToTop(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left:
        NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right:
        NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil) {

        anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    }
    func anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left:
        NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right:
        NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0,leftConstant:
        CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0)
    {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant).isActive = true
        }
        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: bottomConstant).isActive = true
        }
        if let left = left {
            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant).isActive = true
        }
        if let right = right {
            rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: rightConstant).isActive = true
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYXL1.png).

Comment: Check your image fitting is set to aspectFill and that the image is constrained to the size of the cell. To test this, change the image background to a different colour to narrow down the issue.

Comment: i got a class named PageCell and the image i set there the image plus the aspectfill..i think the problem is with my cell height that is not equal to collectionview height..and i dont know how to fix that

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems

1) You are setting the cell's size relative to the view rather than the collectionView.

Your error in setting the cell's size..

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

2) It looks like your backgroundImage for the view doesn't fit 100%. You want to use another aspect ratio to fill the view. You probably want to use .scaleToFill.

[Difference between UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and UIViewContentModeScaleToFill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof)

Comment: hi i did both but still got this red line at the top...any other suggestions?