# How do I scaleType=centerCrop in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to have my UIImageView centerCrop so it fits my width.In my Android version all I need to do is this `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and this is the result.
However, in IOS I am calling Content mode = Center but this is the result
How do I get the same result in my IOS that I have in Android. 
Note I am using Swift 4.2

Android- `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

[image]

IOS

[image]

Comment: try this:  yourImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
As the name suggests, it will scale the image (from center anchor) maintaining its aspect ratio till it fills the imageView

Comment: Doent work....Must be the way I set the UIImageView Up

Comment: How've you set up your views/cells. are you using autolayout?

Comment: I guess that is where my mistake is....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24671000/366346 That should give you a good idea on how things work in iOS

Answer (score 2):

For iOS the scaleTypes you are looking for is UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

See [Difference between UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and UIViewContentModeScaleToFill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof)